# How to use Jenkins Skip Certificate Check plugin?

Tags: jenkins

I´ve installed the Skip Certificate Check plugin on our Jenkins server, re-downloaded slave.jar & jnlp to the agent, but when I start them, I still get the message about the untrusted SSL certificate.
Any advice?

Thanks in advance,
Christian

Comment: Did you figure this out, I'm in the same boat but you got 2 years on me

Comment: No, unfortunately not. :-(
Finally I got our admin setup a proper SSL certificate on the server, so I don´t need to skip the certificate any longer.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47709466/1802348) answer to install correct cert instead of just bypassing it!

Answer (score 3):

Add `-noCertificateCheck` to the arguments for slave.jar.

If I understand the Skip Certificate Check Plugin correctly (I haven't used it) it makes the Jenkins Master process skip cert checks. E.g. to ignore the warning, when checking for updates, if you have a self-signed cert for your Subversion server.

If I understand your problem, it seems to be to get the slave to connect to the master when the master has a self-signed cert. The switch above makes the slave-process ignore cert warnings when it's connecting to the master.