# Public SSL certificate Error

Tags: jenkins, ssl-certificate

We have done the setup for JIRA with Jenkins. From Jira side, it displayed Jenkins job but from Jenkins side not able to connect Jira. SSL certificate issue is getting displayed

Requirement:  Jenkins integration with Jira.

1)      Jenkins should be integrated with Jira
2)      update tickets automatically when a job is built successfully or failed.
3)      Create bug in Jira if test failed

Done Till Now.
1)       Created code to run the test using mvn and SVN
2)      Integrated SVN to Jenkins [working fine]
3)      Install Jira plugin, JiraTestResultReporter, Jiraissueupdater

[image]
Please help me to get public SSL certificate

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps!

Step 1 : Get root certificate of https://www.google.com

1. Open https://www.google.com in a chrome browser.
2. Select Inspect from context menu(right clicking on page) and navigate to security tab
3. Click on view certificates
4. Click on top most certificate on hierarchy and confirm it is tailed with Root CA phrase.
5. drag and drop that image which you saw written certificate on desktop.

Thats it! you got your root certificate!

Step 2 : install certificate to your java cacerts

please verify you have system variable JAVA_HOME declared and you will perform these steps on that jre cacerts only!

1. Navigate to cacerts by JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
2. Download and install keytool explorer it is available for all platforms
3. open cacerts in that tool and import cetificate by "import trusted certificate" button.
4. Save your changes (you may come across issue if it is mac and you do not have write access!)

Step 3 : Restart jenkins

You should not get ssl handshake problem now onwards.

Comment: Thank you  @positivecrux. Step 1 was what was needed in my case. Once I had the certificate file (.cer) I just double clicked on it to import it to the keychain (my  Jenkins slave runs on a mac). Once I added it to the keychain and re-ran my Jenkins project everything worked fine. I did not need a restart of the Jenkins slave. I do have a command in the build that unlocks the keychain though.